# Ошибка при установке библиотеки Keras

Tags: python, python-3.x, нейронные-сети, pip, keras

Стоит Anaconda 3.5 (python 3.6), установлен tensorflow, но при попытке установить Keras выводится следующая ошибка:[image: pip install keras]

TF работает без проблем. Другие нужные библиотеки, такие как numpy стоят.
Что это за проблема и какие возможны варианты решения?

Comment: Как хапускаете установку? `conda install keras`? Попробуйте использовать sudo.

Comment: Нет, pip install keras. Терминал запущена у пространства из Анаконды. И команду sudo она не понимает. Тут через просто через pip

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Проблема решена установкой альтернативным способом из github:

`git clone https://github.com/fchollet/keras.git`

```
cd keras
sudo python setup.py install
```

Подробнее на оф.сайте:
https://keras.io/#installation